# Beamer : two different styles for frames

Tags: beamer

I'd like to make a presentation about networking for 16yo childs. Some of my transparents are for everyone to understand, others are more "level Jedi 2"...

I use a Warsaw theme with beamer, I'd like some of my transparents to appear with a different color.

Can I do that ?

Thanks for any help.

\bye

EDIT : OK, someone gave me a "solution" for my problem, which seems quite simple. But in my case, it doesn't work :

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \useinnertheme{rounded}
%  \usecolortheme{orchid}
%  \usecolortheme{wolverine}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{jedi}[true]{%
    \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=red!80!black}
}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{%
  \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=beamer@blendedblue}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  A normal frame
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[jedi]
  A ``red flag'' frame
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  Another normal frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

But uncommenting the lines

```
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}
```

destroys the "jedi" formatting. Can someone help me on this one ?

I'll explore other solutions, but this one looked so simple :-(

Thanks.

\bye

Comment: Probably related/interesting: [Change beamer theme mid document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22145/134144) and [How can I change the colour scheme of a beamer presentation between different slides?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/261163/134144)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `wolverine` colour theme is a bit "special". It does not define the individual elements based on other colours, e.g. the `structure` colour, like many other colour themes do. Instead it uses hard coded colours, you'll need to change them manually one-by-one.

For example for the two most noticeable colours, the `frametitle` colour and the `palette primary`, you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \useinnertheme{rounded}
  \usecolortheme{orchid}
  \usecolortheme{wolverine}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{jedi}[true]{%
    \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=red!80!black}
    \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=red!80!black}
    \setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=red!80!black}
}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{%
  \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=beamer@blendedblue}
  \setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=yellow!85!orange}
  \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=yellow!90!orange}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{title}
  A normal frame
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[jedi]
  \frametitle{title}
  A ``red flag'' frame
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{title}
  Another normal frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]